# How do I load a view from a specific (shared) path in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter for several projects.

What I haven't figured out how to do is have "shared" views across projects.

For example, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
$this->load->view ("mysharedview");
```

Where mysharedview.php does not exist in my project's application/views folder, but in a shared location that is used by all projects.

Anyone know of a way to do this that doesn't require modifying the core CI files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at Matchbox??

it seems that it can do what you want..

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Matchbox

Comment: Had not looked at Matchbox yet -- perfect for what I'm trying to do.  Thanks.