# Sharing controllers, models and views between separate projects in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, kohana

Kohana, due to cascading file system and modules, allows to share code in common projects, that contains controllers, views and models directories. How can I do it in codeigniter? I want to create sites, that will share some code (admin area views, some models). That is easy in Kohana, we just have to add another directory for Kohana::find_file().

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a duplication of:

[Codeigniter Shared Resources - Opinions Wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247728/codeigniter-shared-resources-opinions-wanted)

**And**

[How do I load a view from a specific (shared) path in CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176561/how-do-i-load-a-view-from-a-specific-shared-path-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1):

I'm more experienced in Kohana than CI but if I'm right there is a HMVC module in CodeIgniter. You could see if you are able to request a external page like you can with the HMVC of kohana.

If I may ask. why do you use codeigniter when you know kohana does the job better?

Comment: Because I am not the one who decides here:) CodeIgniter is more commonly known than Kohana, it is easier to find CI programmer.

Comment: While I have to agree with the more known and more CI programmer. Isn't is smarter to go with the best solution. Kohana doesn't differ that much from CI so finding programmers should not really be a problem. But that is my own opinion